# Get dynamic pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react. I am making a custom scrollbar and I need to get the current `window.pageYOffset`, but `useEffect` cannot work with it. How can I get the current `window.pageYOffset`.

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: I only need to get the current window.pageYOfsset and that's it. And I can't do that

Comment: `window.pageYOffset` should be available from anywhere. Because of this, it's more likely that you're doing it wrong. However, you don't provide a minimal example demonstrating your issue so we can't help you troubleshoot.